# Can't install NuGet package Serilog.Sinks.*

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am facing a problem to install packages of Serilog.Sinks in an old project, e.g. when I try installing Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer I get the following error:

[An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for Serilog.2.6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh0fn.png)

I have already installed package Serilog.2.6.0 and the process went fine, I tried running the code that uses this library and it works okay, but in case I try to uninstall this package I get the error:

[Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/066qc.png)

Thus, I think that something might be wrong with Serilog.2.6.0 in my machine, since I cannot uninstall it or install any of its sinks, but I can't figure out the problem.

Details:

- Visual Studio 2015
- .NET Framework 4.5 Web Forms

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, please let me know the latest status for this issue.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I tried all possibilities, except updating NuGet to newer version, and still facing the issue, no matter which package of Serilog family I install first, I won't be able to install the others or uninstall the one already installed. Since I am working on VDI for the client, I don't have the permission of upgrading the NuGet, so I made the request and am waiting to hear from them, this is why I haven't responded if I've found the solution yet. Thanks!

Comment: That is OK, if you have any update for this issue, please let me know for free :).

Comment: The thing that worked for this case, from those I tried, is copying the references (.dll files) from another project where they're working fine. Thank you for your answers! :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could convert your comment as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread

Answer (score 0):

Hi this worked for me  nugget install Serilog.Sinks

Comment: to add a version type -version 2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

If you can't uninstall your nuget via package manager console or with Nuget Package Manager, you still have the option to uninstall it. Open your package.config file.

Looks like this:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

There you will find the id of `Serilog` your dependency with the version associated. Remove that line. And then unload your project, edit it, there you will find the `HintPath` of `Serilog`:

Looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Serilog.2.6.0\lib\net46\Serilog.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Then the package `Serilog` could be uninstalled complete by manually.

Besides, if you re-install that package still get the same error after uninstall it, this issue should be more related to the NuGet rather than the package `Serilog`.

In this case, please try to uninstall the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015 from Tools->Extensions and Updates, restart Visual Studio. Then install the latest version NuGet:

https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/latest/NuGet.Tools.vsix

After the installation is completed, Reopen the Visual Studio in Administrator mode (right-clicked Visual Studio and started in Administrator mode), try to install that package again, check if it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for this case, from those I tried, is copying the references (.dll files) from another project where they're working fine. Thank you for your answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with me with the following package.config setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Serilog" version="2.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog.Exceptions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Serilog.Sinks.File" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```